# fscanf consumes first letter in file. How do I fix it?

Tags: c, computer-science

I am making a program for a class that reads the contents of a .csv file. I am using a while loop inside of a for loop to scan the contents into two separate arrays, and when it prints the contents, everything is right, except it is missing the first letter in the file. We are not allowed to use any functions from the library except what is permitted.

Code in question:

```
void readFile(FILE *fptr, int size)
{
  int i, a;
  a = size / 2;
  printf("number of lines in readFile is %d:\n", size);
  double y[50];
  char x[50];
  for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
      while (fscanf(fptr,"%c,%lf,", &x[i], &y[i]) ==2);
    }
  printf("%c, %.2lf: ", x[0], y[0]);
  //a loop to make sure it scanned properly by displaying array contents
  for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
      printf("%c, %.2lf:\n", x[i], y[i]);
    }
}
```

I tried with no luck to !feof(fptr), != EOF, but these are not supposed to be used in the intro class I am taking. I am out of ideas to fix it.
This is the output of the program above:

```
number of lines in readFile is 4:
, 20.00: 
, 20.00:
E, 30.00:
number of lines is 4:
```

Comment: Try space: `"%c,%lf,"` --> `" %c,%lf,"`.   Remember `'\n'` is a character too.

Comment: Post some sample file input and expected output.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the logic of having the `while` loop inside the `for` loop?

Comment: `while (fscanf(fptr,"%c,%lf,", &x[i], &y[i]) ==2);` seems odd. Do you expect it to read successfully more than once? If it does it'll read all the data into the same variables and whatever was read last will be kept with earlier data overwritten and lost.

Comment: Ninja, I think you identify the issue,  while ((fscanf(fptr,"%c,%lf,", &x[i], &y[i]) ==2) && i<a) {i++;}, made be a solution.

Comment: @MZM Or just remove the `while` and let the `for` loop do exactly what you proposed.

Comment: Sure, but may want to guard against reading beyond EOF if size don't match actual number of lines in file.  But certainly just working with the information giving, for loop will work.

Comment: Ninja yes. The purpose of the for loop is to increase the array size (x[i]) that way the position increases until it is the same size as a. Each time it loops the data is input into the new array position.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues ...

1. The `fscanf` format is wrong. It needs a leading space to skip over newlines.
2. Unless you intend to operate on the data read in `readFile` (vs. passing it back to caller), having function scoped `x` and `y` arrays will go out of scope when the function returns.
3. The caller of `readFile` should pass the *maximum* array count but let the function determine the actual number of entries.
4. Whenever I see two or more "parallel" arrays [indexed by the same variable], I would use a `struct`. Particularly for `.csv` data.
5. `.csv` files are of the form: `a,b\nc,d\n` and *not* `a,b,\nc,d,\n` so the trailing `,` in the `fscanf` is incorrect.
6. Using nested loops for the data input doesn't work.
7. No need for `feof`. Just loop until the `fscanf` return is *not* 2.

---

Here is the corrected code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// data for single .csv line
struct data {
    char x;
    double y;
};

// readFile -- read in .csv file
// RETURNS: count of records/lines read
size_t
readFile(FILE *fptr, struct data *arr, size_t size)
// fptr -- open file stream
// arr -- pointer to data array
// size -- maximum number of elements in arr
{
    int count = 0;

    while (1) {
        // check for overflow of array
        if (count >= size) {
            fprintf(stderr,"readFile: too much data for array\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // point to current struct/record
        struct data *cur = &arr[count];

        // read in the .csv line -- stop on error or EOF
        if (fscanf(fptr, " %c,%lf", &cur->x, &cur->y) != 2)
            break;

        // advance the count of the number of valid elements
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    struct data arr[50];

    // skip over program name
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc != 1) {
        printf("wrong number of arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // open the input file
    FILE *fptr = fopen(argv[0],"r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        perror(argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    // read in the data lines
    size_t count = readFile(fptr,arr,sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
    fclose(fptr);

    // print the array
    for (size_t idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx) {
        struct data *cur = &arr[idx];
        printf("%c, %.2f:\n",cur->x,cur->y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the sample input I used to test the program:

```
J,23
D,37.62
F,17.83
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
J, 23.00:
D, 37.62:
F, 17.83:
```